# How to take a string after the slash?

Tags: php, string, url, var

Like:

```
"http://www.blog-name.com/search/taio cruz"

---------------------------------------------^
 "Sorry, no posts were found with the
tag taio cruz"
```

The Problem:

If the user enters `http://www.blog-name.com/search/taio cruz`, the browser will look for a *folder* named "taio cruz", won't it ?

How can I get the value "Taio Cruz"?

Comment: Plz watch caps and see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine

Answer (score 5):

```
echo basename("http://www.blog-name.com/search/taio cruz"); //taio cruz
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$url = 'http://www.blog-name.com/search/taio cruz';
$val = end(explode('/', $url));
// $val is now 'taio cruz'
```

Comment: This have the obvious downside of having to find all slashes and creating an intermediary array for an otherwise simple problem.

Comment: @Emil it's a clean solution. Performance isn't really going to take that much of a hit, and it doesn't really matter that much in the first place

Comment: No, it's not a clean solution. I agree that the performance hit may be infinitesimal, but creating an intermediary array (which includes allocating space in memory, building hash buckets and whatnot) is not clean by my definitions.

Comment: @Emil it's a clean solution because it's readable and understandable. Using `strrpos` (while convenient and perhaps more efficient) is hard to understand because the function has a terrible name. You worry too much about the internals, the point is to use the abstractions to your advantage.

Comment: Everyone knows what strpos and friends does (or should, at least, if they make a living writing PHP code). By your logic, your code could just as well `end` the world in a big `explosion`. I think it's lazy, especially since the complexity of writing them is almost the same.

Comment: @Emil not everyone knows what `strrpos` does and it's difficult (visually) to differentiate it from plain `strpos`.

Comment: I think we can agree on that we disagree on this topic :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
$url = 'http://www.blog-name.com/search/taio cruz';
$last = substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);
//$last is now "taio cruz"
```

Comment: If you type
http://www.blog-name.com/search/taio cruz
The browser will look for the folder named "Taio Cruz", wont it ?

Comment: You can replace `$url` with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` if you want to do it for the current page. I just showed a general way to do it.

Comment: @Bernaz You'll have to combine this approach with modrewrite to route requests through a PHP file which may not match the requested URL.